# Read all the log files from the folder

Tags: java

I want to read all the log files from a folder. I am reading just a file now. I have set the path for the log files as `String dir`. And I have list of other exceptions which more or less do the same thing as `getExternalServiceException`.How do I read all the log files from `D:\\logs` using `for loop` OR `for each loop`.

**Alert - I need to use Java v1.6**

```
public class CallingCheck 
{


    public void getExternalServiceException(String sPath) {
        BufferedReader br = null;
        try {
            File f = new File(sPath);
            if(f.isFile())
            {

            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(sPath);
            DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(fis);
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(dis));
            String strLine;

            String sPattern = "at (.*)\\.(.*)\\(([^:]*):?([\\d]*)\\)";

            Pattern p = Pattern.compile(sPattern);

            boolean bFlag = false;
             int  iCount = 0;
             int totCount = 0;
            int exCount = 0;


            while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {

                if((strLine.contains("com.shop.integration.exception.ExternalServiceException")))
                        //
                {   exCount++;
                    bFlag = true;

                }
                if(bFlag){

                    if((strLine.contains("** Error"))){


                    Matcher m = p.matcher(strLine);
                    if(m.find()){
                        totCount++;
                        iCount++;

                    if(iCount==1){
                        System.out.println("Class name:- " + m.group(3));
                        System.out.println("Line Number:- " + m.group(4));
                        System.out.println("ExternalServiceException occurence count: " + exCount);

                        System.out.println("ExternalServiceException stack trace count: " + totCount);

                    }
                    if(strLine.contains("at")){
                        String sTemp[] = strLine.split("\\s+at+\\s+");

                        strLine = sTemp[1];
                        strLine = "at   "+strLine;
                    }
                    System.out.println(strLine);


                    if(iCount == 5){
                        bFlag = false;  
                        iCount=0;
                    }

                    }
                }

            }
            }}}
         catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }finally{
            try{
            if(br != null){
                br.close();
            }
            }catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String dir= "D:\\logs\\readLogFiles.txt";

        CallingCheck check = new CallingCheck();
        check.getExternalServiceException(dir);


    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`File.listFiles`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles()):

```
File[] fileList = new File(directory).listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {
            @Override
            public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
                return true; // we simply want all the files in this directory
                            // but you can edit to accept specific files
                           // only depending on certain conditions
            }
        });

for (File file : fileList) { 
    // handle each file - read/write etc
}
```

Using a lambda (Java 8) is even cooler:

```
File[] fileList = new File(directory).listFiles((dir, name) -> {
    return true; // we simply want all the files in this directory
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This code should do the trick:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    File inputFolder = new File("your_directory_here");
    for(File inputFile : inputFolder.listFiles())
    {
        // ignore files that aren't log files
        if(!f.getName().endsWith("log"))
            continue;

        // call a separate method to deal with each file
        processFile(inputFile);
    }
}

private static void processFile(File logFile)
{
    // enter your logic here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code to get all the files in a folder

```
File folder = new File("/Users/you/folder/");
File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

for (File file : listOfFiles) {
if (file.isFile()) {
    System.out.println(file.getName());
}
}
```

Comment: This will give me list of files in the folder. I want to read all those files as well. If I use the path as `File` object, how do I pass the `dir` path which I have in `main` method.